# Determine the network interface which a new connection established from - Python socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

Let's say I'm implementing a TCP server using Python socket.
As part of the implementation, I'm using:

```
self.sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8080))
```

When `self.sock` is the socket I'm using for listening to new connections.
To the best of my knowledge, I know that whenever we're binding the listening socket to address `'0.0.0.0'` - it means that we're listening to new connections from any valid network interface.

Now, let's assume that a new TCP connection was established and we got the following tuple:

```
(connection_sock, client_addr) = self.sock.accept()
```

I would like to ask if there's any possibility to determine the network interface which the new TCP connection was established from?

Note: By using the term "network interface" I mean for example to "eth0", "lo", etc.

Thanks!

Comment: A TCP connection is identified by source and destination IP addresses and source and destination TCP addresses (ports). You will have the destination IP address as part of the connection identifier.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for your comment. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but my goal is to determine the "network interface" which forwarded the first SYN packet (sent by the client to my server) to my server process.
When "network interface" means for example "eth0", "lo", "enp0s1", etc.

Comment: The interface will be the one with the destination IP address. You simply need to associate the connection destination IP address to the IP address assigned to an interface.

Comment: `self.sock.accept()` won't tell you the local IP that accepted the connection, only the IP of the remote client. But, you can call `connection_sock.getsockname()` afterwards to get the local IP, and then you can enumerate the local interfaces looking for the one that is assigned that IP.